# Java split regexp when delimiter is part of the data

Tags: java, regex

Sorry if this question has already been solved, or closed but I have been searching for long without an answer.

I have to split lines I am receiving from an external systems, using the `~` delimiter.

I have an issue because some data contain `~~` (~ repeated twice) and in this case the data must not be split.

So if I receive `A~B~C~~C~D` I want this split back:
`A, B, C~~C, D`

I cannot figure out what regular expression I have to used not to split `~~`.

Comment: What is your current regex?

Comment: As I love edge cases - what should happen to `A~B~~~C`

Comment: my regexp was just "~". About the edge cases A~B~~~C will never happen. We would have A~B~~C instead and should be split as A, B~~C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `(?<!~)~(?!~)` with a negative look-ahead and look-behind for `~`.

**Example**

```
String test = "A~B~C~~D~E";
System.out.println(
    Arrays.toString(
        test.split("(?<!~)~(?!~)")
    )
);
```

**Output**

```
[A, B, C~~D, E]
```

This should also work with more than two consecutive `~`s, e.g. with `"A~B~C~~~D~E"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can split by

```
\b~\b
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/t3D2Jp/1

You can use

```
(?:^|\b)~(?:$|\b)
```

if you want to remove trailing ones too

Comment: You might also want to get the trailing `~`, ie `b~a~`. In this case you can write `(^|\b)~($|\b)`

Comment: @flkes thanx added

Comment: I think making the groups non-capturing here is redundant?

Comment: @flkes capturing them would not be of any use :)

Comment: ahh, I see now. More coffee for me